# Не запускается intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, intelij

Не запускается intellij idea, нет никакой реакиции и в фоновых процессах не появляется, оперативной памяти хватает, перезапуск Винды не помогает.

Comment: Она никогда не запускалась или перестала?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в своей операционной системе нового пользователя и попробуйте установить IDE под новым пользователем. Иногда это помогает.